Dock options Ubuntu 24.04
I have loaded Ubuntu 24.04 on a new machine and would like to move the docked application bar from middle bottom to the the left hand side of the screen (Gnome 46). The dock options in settings is no longer there. Has anyone figured out how to move it? Thanks!

Go to Settings > Ubuntu Desktop > Dock > Position on screen.  There are three options: Bottom, left, and right.

I've found a Reddit thread that tells me to install the following package:
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock

However, the package was already installed on my machine, so I tried reinstalling the package instead:
sudo apt-get reinstall gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock

After a reboot, the Dock options reappeared. I hope this helps.
